# "Job enquiry" in German?

Tags: translation, word-usage, word-choice

I am writing an e-mail (in German) enquiring about job vacancies in some company and I am having difficulty picking an appropriate subject (Betreff) for the e-mail.

I would like to put something equivalent to **job enquiry**, and the best translations that I came up with are **Stellenanfrage** and **Jobanfrage**. However, I am not sure if these words are a correct (or the best) choice.

Are the above suggestions in the spirit of the German language, and are they appropriate translations of **job enquiry**?

Comment: I think *Stellenanfrage* sounds way better than *Jobanfrage*. While “job” is heavily-used, I find it rather misplaced in a compound with *-anfrage*, where *Stelle* is perfectly valid. You also use *Stellenausschreibung* and never *Jobausschreibung*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both words are correct, but I think not the best choice.

**Jobanfrage** A job is a colloquial German word for a job. I would not use it in an job enquiry unless it is a easygoing company and you are well known. And even then, I would not use it. A job enquiry is a serious thing and then you should show, that you take the job serious.

Instead of *Stellenanfrage* (ask for a job) I would use the expression *Bewerbung* (job application).

I recommend to make a google search for [Bewerbung email](https://www.google.de/search?q=bewerbung%20email).
Some interesting hits:

- http://karrierebibel.de/online-email-bewerbung/
- http://www.stepstone.de/Karriere-Bewerbungstipps/bewerbungstipps/bewerbung-per-email-nicht-an-formfehlern-scheitern.cfm
- http://arbeits-abc.de/bewerbung-per-e-mail/

Some recommendations:

- Don't use only Bewerbung in the subject. Tell what job you want and what you are (student, ...)
- If you answer on a job advertisement, repeat the title of the job advertisement. Mention the reference number if there is one.
- If possible, address a person in the company (No *Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren* but *Sehr geehrte Frau X* X should be the boss of the departement where you want to work or a responsible person of the Human Resources Department)

Good luck for your search.

Comment: Many thanks for your useful answer. The email is not actually an application, as there are no open advertisements at the moment. I would really just like to say that I would love to work there, if my qualifications meet their needs/standards and also in case they plan to hire more staff in near future. So it is really just an enquiry, an informational email outside any official job advertisement/offer.

Comment: According to this site http://karrierebibel.de/blindbewerbung/ (in particular, the template http://karrierebibel.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Blindbewerbung-Mustervorlage.pdf) on the so called "Blindbewerbungen", the word **Bewerbung** is to be used.

Comment: Yes, also in a _Blindbewerbung_ you should use the statement _Bewerbung_. If there is no special job, you offer yoursels, e.g. like _Bewerbung als Softwareentwickler mit Schwerpunkt C++_. With _Bewerbung_ you tell what you want and the rest tells what you offer the employer.

Comment: That is precisely what I did. Thank you very much indeed for all the help and useful advice.